# Running cucumber with bdd in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, cucumber, bdd

I am having problem running this cucumber projects belows. It showing errors on line 7, 8, 20 and 32.

```
package stepDefinition;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;

public class aptitudeTest {

@Given ("I have successfully ([^\"]*)")
public void I have (String str)
{
    if (str.equals("registered"))
    {
        System.out.println("registered Automation");
    }
    {
        System.out.println("unregistered Automation");
    }
}

@When ("I enter my valid ([^\"]*)")
public void I enter (String str)
{
    if (str.equals("credentials"))
    {
        System.out.println("credentials Automation");
    }
    {
        System.out.println("details Automation");
    }
}

    @Then ("I should see the welcome ([^\"]*) him")
    public void I should (String str)
    {
        if  (str.equals("welcome"))
        {
            System.out.println("welcome to your account");
        }
        {
            System.out.println("please enter the correct credential");
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the Feature File

```
Scenario:I should see a message when i successfully logged in

Given I have successfully registered
When I enter my valid credentials
Then I should see the welcome message
```

Comment: I mean no disrespect, but your best step is to take an introductory java class.

Comment: You should look at how you are naming the methods? Names cannot have spaces. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html#naming

Answer (score 1):

There are many 2 issues with the feature file and how the Given, When & Then are used.

1. The method name should not have any spaces.
2. If you're passing the argument in to the method, it should be in quotes. 
   ex. I have successfully registered should be as 'I have successfully "registered"'. Also the corresponding method should be annotated as "I have successfully \"([^\"]*)\" - You should have an escape character there. The registered will be the string that's passed.

Comment: There is no need to put quotes around the words that should be captured. You may, but you will end up with more a complicated regular expression if you do.